# Apple's most recent Java update removes Java Preferences, how to change from shell?

Tags: java, macos, bash, shell, zsh

Apple's Java update this week removes the Java Preferences.app from Utilities.  When working between different versions of Java in varied development environments it no longer seems easily achievable to change from Java 6 to Sun's 1.7 as before.

I believe that there still should be a shell mechanism in place to accomplish this, however I'm not readily finding it.  ***How do you PROPERLY change the current active version of Java whilst in a shell session?***

(I say PROPERLY because I want to be sure that all env vars are set appropriately such as JAVA_HOME, it's path, etc.)

Additionally, I thought, a couple of years ago, I had stumbled across a script that would change Java env's for you by simply listing the options and then defining which one to switch to.  It may be that I'm getting confused with the tool in Ubuntu, but I am nearly certain it was for OS X...  It would be helpful to either know what this was or perhaps we should write a quick script, if one doesn't exist, that will meet this need; perhaps inserting it into Homebrew?

Comment: You can reinstall Apple's Java 6, which should reinstall the preferences utility (I've not tried this yet), you can grab a copy from http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39490/apple-java

Comment: Well, I'm not so much interested in going "backwards" but rather going forwards with Apple's parameters / constraints.  Therefore working without the old Preferences panel is what I'm trying to understand how to do within OS X since it is usually rather simple to do with Linux distros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MadProgrammer who initially replied to this question.  I got to exploring things a little more and found some examples that helped me with the following script that I'm now using to execute Java applications that will not function with Java 1.7 currently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Or plug in `zsh` instead of `bash` above if that is your preferred shell

DIR=$(pwd)
cd "$DIR"
APPLICATION_NAME="App Name"

echo -n "Locating Java ... "

PLATFORM=$(uname)
JAVA_PATH="java"
JAVA_VER=$($JAVA_PATH -version 2>&1 | sed 's/java version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q')

if [[ "$JAVA_VER" == *"command not found"* ]]; then
    echo "Java not found."
else
    JAVA_VER_FULL=$($JAVA_PATH -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')

    if [[ $JAVA_VER -eq 17 ]]; then
        echo "v1.7 found."

        if [[ $PLATFORM -eq "Darwin" ]]; then
            echo "[!!!] WARNING: Java v1.7 on OS X is known to have problems with ${APPLICATION_NAME}."
            echo -n "Looking for compatible version of Java ... "

            JAVA_PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin/java"
            if [[ -f "$JAVA_PATH" ]]; then
                JAVA_VER=$($JAVA_PATH -version 2>&1 | sed 's/java version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q')
                JAVA_VER_FULL=$($JAVA_PATH -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')
                if [[ $JAVA_VER -eq 16 ]]; then
                    echo "$JAVA_VER_FULL found. Using this version."
                else
                    echo "No known compatible versions of Java could be found. ${APPLICATION_NAME} may not run properly, or at all."
                fi
            fi
        else
            echo "$JAVA_VER_FULL found."
        fi
    else
        echo "$JAVA_VER_FULL found."
    fi
fi

echo ""


echo "Starting ${APPLICATION_NAME}..."


# Insert the java application or jar that you wish to execute here prepended by `$JAVA_PATH` instead of simply `java`
# For example:
#
# $JAVA_PATH -jar /path/to/the/application.jar
```

*One potentially useful situation for this is to create a script to run Minecraft that is having problems with with the 1.7 release scenario.  Obviously there are other similar apps that are having some varying degrees of problems and this will likewise be useful to control the Java version you wish to use rather than just using the default method or trying to hack around the symlinks.*

Comment: Now you just need to make it so you can flip it backwards and forwards depending on what's current set as default...

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks for the question, I needed to work this out myself.

This is what I've learned..

- `whereis java` points to `/usr/bin/java`
- `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`
- On my Mac, `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current` is a symbolic link to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A`, which is currently Java 1.7.0._07-b10

What we need to do is redirect `Current` to the JVM we want to use.

On my system, Java 1.6.0_37 was installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK`, which is symbolic link to `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents`

What I did was...

Make a back up of the `Current`

```
sudo mv Current Current.bak
```

Make a new symbolic link to the `CurrentJDK`

```
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK Current
```

Then at the command line, I did `java -version` and got

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

Now, to move it back, I simply moved the `Current`

```
sudo mv Current Current.1.6
```

Then relinked `Current` to `A`

```
sudo ln -s A Current
```

Then at the command line, I did `java -version` and got

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Now all I need to do is `sudo mv Current Current.1.7` and `sudo mv Current.1.6 Current` to move back and reverse it to move forward.

This solution was inspired by https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4444438?start=0&tstart=0, but I had to play around with it to make sure ;)

**UPDATED**

After some playing around, I created a `java6` symbolic link that lives in `/usr/bin/java6` and points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java`, this basically allows me to execute `java6` from the command line without having to switch the versions out

Comment: Well, this is interesting as you've done exactly what I've done, however I'm having some odd errors now.  You did not have any problems with your environment running java apps after this relinking?

Comment: To be honest, I've not fully tested, but it did give me some weirdness to start with.  I was able to get Netbeans to see 1.6 as a separate platform for the time being :P

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to have to play some more with this then.  Ideally we need to wrap this into a script for inclusion with Homebrew or such as I think this is certainly something that's sorely needed with regards to changing versions.

Comment: You got my vote, it's a pain in the ... fingers to get this to work

Comment: Hey @MadProgrammer, I added another answer here that I think really solves our problem more fully and I've had some solid success with it.  I thought you might be interested in this option.  Appreciate your initial answer!